# Subdomain instead of permalink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm looking for a way to use subdomains as a permalink in rails.

For example:

Instead of `http://domain.com/user2` pointing to `user2`'s profile.

I would like `http://user2.domain.com` to point to `user2`'s profile.

Anyone know of a solution to this that will work on `heroku`?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://richonrails.com/articles/basic-subdomains-in-ruby-on-rails)?  I have not implemented but it looks pretty straightforward and this looks like a good resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes:

```
  get '/' => 'home#index', :constraints => { :subdomain => 'www' } 
  get '/' => 'users#show', :constraints => { :subdomain => /.+/ }
```

Users Controller:

```
@user = User.find_by_permalink(request.subdomain)
```